# Как оптимизировать перебор

Tags: c#, циклы, перебор

Я перебираю все возможные варианты комбинаций. У меня получился вот такой код:

```
private void generate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            schedules = new List<Schedule>();
            foreach(Form form in forms)
            {
                List<Schedule> variations = new List<Schedule>();
                List<Lesson>[] lessonVariations = new List<Lesson>[36];
                int id = 0;
                for(int i1 = 0; i1 < form.lessons.Count; i1++)
                    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < form.lessons.Count; i2++)
                        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < form.lessons.Count; i3++)
                            for (int i4 = 0; i4 < form.lessons.Count; i4++)
                                for (int i5 = 0; i5 < form.lessons.Count; i5++)
                                    for (int i6 = 0; i6 < form.lessons.Count; i6++)
                                        for (int i7 = 0; i7 < form.lessons.Count; i7++)
                                            for (int i8 = 0; i8 < form.lessons.Count; i8++)
                                                for (int i9 = 0; i9 < form.lessons.Count; i9++)
                                                    for (int i10 = 0; i10 < form.lessons.Count; i10++)
                                                        for (int i11 = 0; i11 < form.lessons.Count; i11++)
                                                            for (int i12 = 0; i12 < form.lessons.Count; i12++)
                                                                for (int i13 = 0; i13 < form.lessons.Count; i13++)
                                                                    for (int i14 = 0; i14 < form.lessons.Count; i14++)
                                                                        for (int i15 = 0; i15 < form.lessons.Count; i15++)
                                                                            for (int i16 = 0; i16 < form.lessons.Count; i16++)
                                                                                for (int i17 = 0; i17 < form.lessons.Count; i17++)
                                                                                    for (int i18 = 0; i18 < form.lessons.Count; i18++)
                                                                                        for (int i19 = 0; i19 < form.lessons.Count; i19++)
                                                                                            for (int i20 = 0; i20 < form.lessons.Count; i20++)
                                                                                                for (int i21 = 0; i21 < form.lessons.Count; i21++)
                                                                                                    for (int i22 = 0; i22 < form.lessons.Count; i22++)
                                                                                                        for (int i23 = 0; i23 < form.lessons.Count; i23++)
                                                                                                            for (int i24 = 0; i24 < form.lessons.Count; i24++)
                                                                                                                for (int i25 = 0; i25 < form.lessons.Count; i25++)
                                                                                                                    for (int i26 = 0; i26 < form.lessons.Count; i26++)
                                                                                                                        for (int i27 = 0; i27 < form.lessons.Count; i27++)
                                                                                                                            for (int i28 = 0; i28 < form.lessons.Count; i28++)
                                                                                                                                for (int i29 = 0; i29 < form.lessons.Count; i29++)
                                                                                                                                    for (int i30 = 0; i30 < form.lessons.Count; i30++)
                                                                                                                                        for (int i31 = 0; i31 < form.lessons.Count; i31++)
                                                                                                                                            for (int i32 = 0; i32 < form.lessons.Count; i32++)
                                                                                                                                                for (int i33 = 0; i33 < form.lessons.Count; i33++)
                                                                                                                                                    for (int i34 = 0; i34 < form.lessons.Count; i34++)
                                                                                                                                                        for (int i35 = 0; i35 < form.lessons.Count; i35++)
                                                                                                                                                            for (int i36 = 0; i36 < form.lessons.Count; i36++)
                                                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                                                                variations.Add(new Schedule());

                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[0].lessons[0] = form.lessons[i1];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[0].lessons[1] = form.lessons[i2];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[0].lessons[2] = form.lessons[i3];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[0].lessons[3] = form.lessons[i4];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[0].lessons[4] = form.lessons[i5];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[0].lessons[5] = form.lessons[i6];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[1].lessons[0] = form.lessons[i7];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[1].lessons[1] = form.lessons[i8];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[1].lessons[2] = form.lessons[i9];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[1].lessons[3] = form.lessons[i10];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[1].lessons[4] = form.lessons[i11];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[1].lessons[5] = form.lessons[i12];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[2].lessons[0] = form.lessons[i13];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[2].lessons[1] = form.lessons[i14];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[2].lessons[2] = form.lessons[i15];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[2].lessons[3] = form.lessons[i16];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[2].lessons[4] = form.lessons[i17];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[2].lessons[5] = form.lessons[i18];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[3].lessons[0] = form.lessons[i19];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[3].lessons[1] = form.lessons[i20];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[3].lessons[2] = form.lessons[i21];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[3].lessons[3] = form.lessons[i22];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[3].lessons[4] = form.lessons[i23];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[3].lessons[5] = form.lessons[i24];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[4].lessons[0] = form.lessons[i25];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[4].lessons[1] = form.lessons[i26];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[4].lessons[2] = form.lessons[i27];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[4].lessons[3] = form.lessons[i28];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[4].lessons[4] = form.lessons[i29];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[4].lessons[5] = form.lessons[i30];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[5].lessons[0] = form.lessons[i31];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[5].lessons[1] = form.lessons[i32];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[5].lessons[2] = form.lessons[i33];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[5].lessons[3] = form.lessons[i34];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[5].lessons[4] = form.lessons[i35];
                                                                                                                                                                variations[id].days[5].lessons[5] = form.lessons[i36];

                                                                                                                                                                id++;
                                                                                                                                                            }

            }
        }
```

Абсолютно полностью уверен, что это далеко не самое лучшее использование возможностей с#. Чтобы не засорять память я буду сразу проверять подходит ли нам такая комбинация, но как это более умно оформить?

Comment: Объясните, что делает ваш код, ибо я сейчас в шоке сижу и недоумеваю, на кой вам цикл под каждый элемент?

Comment: У меня есть уроки и есть время, в которое их можно проводить (всего 36, можно проводить по 6 уроков на протяжении 6 дней). Перебираю все возможные варианты расписания.

Comment: Вообще-то такое по-нормальному делается одним циклом, гуглите **алгоритм генерации размещений** или выборок. Но сначала подумайте вот над чем: если у вас есть хотя бы 2 урока, то на выходе вы получите аж 2^36 = 68 719 476 736 вариантов расписания, на каждый из которых вам потребуется как минимум 36*8 байт (это очень грубая оценка снизу). У вас есть 18 терабайт ОЗУ для хранения всей этой радости?

Answer (score 0):

Разумеется, можно сократить эти 36 циклов. Вот пример

```
        int globalCount = 3; //form.lessons.Count
        int[] slots = new int[36]; //по умолчанию проинициализированы нулями
        int finishIndex = slots.Length - 1;
        do
        {
            DoSomethingUseful();//полезная нагрузка здесь
            //генерация следующего расписания
            slots[0]++;
            if (finishIndex == 0 && slots[0] == globalCount)
            {
                break;
            }
            int overflowIndex = 0;
            while (slots[overflowIndex] == globalCount)
            {
                slots[overflowIndex] %= globalCount;
                overflowIndex++;
                slots[overflowIndex]++;
                if (overflowIndex == finishIndex && slots[overflowIndex] == globalCount - 1)
                {
                    finishIndex--;
                }
            }
        }
        while (true);
```

Только учтите, что изначальная некрасивость вашего кода (36 циклов) отражает сложность алгоритма (n^36), где n - количество вариантов уроков. При n > 2, если у вас нет суперкомпьютера под рукой, вы не сможете дождаться окончания работы алгоритма. При n > 4, вам не поможет даже современный суперкомпьютер.

Answer (score -1):

У вас изначально код имеет довольно странную архитектуру, давайте немного разберем.

```
variations.Add(new Schedule());

variations[id].days[0].lessons[0] = form.lessons[i1];
variations[id].days[0].lessons[1] = form.lessons[i2];
variations[id].days[0].lessons[2] = form.lessons[i3];
variations[id].days[0].lessons[3] = form.lessons[i4];
variations[id].days[0].lessons[4] = form.lessons[i5];
variations[id].days[0].lessons[5] = form.lessons[i6];
variations[id].days[1].lessons[0] = form.lessons[i7];
variations[id].days[1].lessons[1] = form.lessons[i8];
variations[id].days[1].lessons[2] = form.lessons[i9];
variations[id].days[1].lessons[3] = form.lessons[i10];
variations[id].days[1].lessons[4] = form.lessons[i11];
variations[id].days[1].lessons[5] = form.lessons[i12];
variations[id].days[2].lessons[0] = form.lessons[i13];
variations[id].days[2].lessons[1] = form.lessons[i14];
variations[id].days[2].lessons[2] = form.lessons[i15];
variations[id].days[2].lessons[3] = form.lessons[i16];
variations[id].days[2].lessons[4] = form.lessons[i17];
variations[id].days[2].lessons[5] = form.lessons[i18];
variations[id].days[3].lessons[0] = form.lessons[i19];
variations[id].days[3].lessons[1] = form.lessons[i20];
variations[id].days[3].lessons[2] = form.lessons[i21];
variations[id].days[3].lessons[3] = form.lessons[i22];
variations[id].days[3].lessons[4] = form.lessons[i23];
variations[id].days[3].lessons[5] = form.lessons[i24];
variations[id].days[4].lessons[0] = form.lessons[i25];
variations[id].days[4].lessons[1] = form.lessons[i26];
variations[id].days[4].lessons[2] = form.lessons[i27];
variations[id].days[4].lessons[3] = form.lessons[i28];
variations[id].days[4].lessons[4] = form.lessons[i29];
variations[id].days[4].lessons[5] = form.lessons[i30];
variations[id].days[5].lessons[0] = form.lessons[i31];
variations[id].days[5].lessons[1] = form.lessons[i32];
variations[id].days[5].lessons[2] = form.lessons[i33];
variations[id].days[5].lessons[3] = form.lessons[i34];
variations[id].days[5].lessons[4] = form.lessons[i35];
variations[id].days[5].lessons[5] = form.lessons[i36];
```

Что мы тут имеем?

1. Создание пустого объекта и дальнейший поиск его:

   - `variations.Add(new Schedule());` - вы создаете новый объект с пустыми значениями.
   - `variations[id]` - вы ищите пустой созданный объект по его индексу и задаете некоторые далее значения.

   Тут собственно вопрос, а почему бы сразу не сделать класс `Schedule` с нужными значениями?
2. Дублирование кода:

   - Значение `days` у вас идет от 0 и до 5, также значение `lessons` у вас имеет аналогичную нумерацию. Вы это не руками должны писать, а автоматизировать тем же циклом.
   - `form.lessons[i1]` - Тут тоже нечего такого у вас нет, лишь значение от 1 до 36 и тоже можно автоматизировать.

Исходя из всего этого, ваш код можно сократить до простого:

```
int itemIndex = 1;
for (int day = 0; day <= 5; day++)
{
    for (int lesson = 0; lesson <= 5; lesson++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{day}][{lesson}] {itemIndex}");
        itemIndex++;
    }
}
```

Вместо `Console.WriteLine` вы заносите нужные вам объекты туда, куда надо. Результатом данного кода будет:

```
[0][0] 1
[0][1] 2
[0][2] 3
[0][3] 4
[0][4] 5
[0][5] 6
[1][0] 7
[1][1] 8
[1][2] 9
[1][3] 10
[1][4] 11
[1][5] 12
[2][0] 13
[2][1] 14
[2][2] 15
[2][3] 16
[2][4] 17
[2][5] 18
[3][0] 19
[3][1] 20
[3][2] 21
[3][3] 22
[3][4] 23
[3][5] 24
[4][0] 25
[4][1] 26
[4][2] 27
[4][3] 28
[4][4] 29
[4][5] 30
[5][0] 31
[5][1] 32
[5][2] 33
[5][3] 34
[5][4] 35
[5][5] 36
```

Как видим, 36 значений, 5 `days` и 5 `lessons`, без кучи циклов.

Если пойти дальше, то `days` и `lessons` можно сделать коллекциями (`List<T>`), тогда нам не нужен будет индекс вовсе и можно будет еще сильнее сократить код.

Comment: Окей, это понятно, но меня больше смущает 36 циклов for.

Comment: @РостиславЛипский Ну если вы мне скажете на кой черт они вам сдались, тогда поговорим про них. В ответе я переписал ваш код и вроде он дает тот результат, который вы и хотели, если не так, то поясните конкретней что вам нужно.